# I am developing a hybrid app using react-native webview. You cannot control the web view screen

Tags: reactjs, react-native, webview

I am developing a hybrid app using `react-native` `WebView`. I have completed the part to open the `WebView`, but I cannot touch the buttons of the website or use the functions at all. It's as if the image was just printed. How do I use the web view screen?

```
    import React from 'react';
    import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';
    import { ScrollView } from 'react-native';
    
    export const WebViewArea = () => {
        return (
            <ScrollView style={{ height: 700 }}>
                <WebView source={{ uri: 'https://naver.com' }}
                    style={{ marginTop: 20, height: 700 }}
                />
            </ScrollView>
        )
    }
```

I'm writing it functionally, and for the root App.js, it's like this:

```
    const App = () => {
      const isDarkMode = useColorScheme() === 'dark';
    
      const backgroundStyle = {
        backgroundColor: isDarkMode ? Colors.darker : Colors.lighter,
      };
    
      return (
        <SafeAreaView style={backgroundStyle}>
          <WebViewArea />
        </SafeAreaView>
      );
    };
```